# average wind direction using histc matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello this question might be easy but i am struggling to get average wind directions for 1 year. I need hourly averages to compare with concentration measurements. My wind measurements are every minute in degree. So my idea was to use the `histc` function in matlab to get the most common winddirection within the hour. this works for 1 h but how do i create a loop which gives me hourly values for a year.

here is the code

```
wdd=winddirections in degree(vectorsize e.g for a year 525600)

binranges = [0:10:360];

[bincounts,ind] = histc(wdd(1:60),binranges);
[num idx] = max(bincounts(:));
wd_out=binranges(idx);
```

kind regards matthias

Comment: If you are looking to keep a bin count, make these changes - `histc(reshape(wdd,60,[]),binranges)` and `max(bincounts)`, rest of the code stays the same. If you are looking to have average values, Ander's solution posted here looks good to me.

Comment: I had to post the [solution code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26802780/3293881), as the comments didn't read the codes properly. If any of the solutions listed here work for you, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one -

```
binranges = [0:10:360]
[bincounts,ind]  = histc(reshape(wdd,60,[]),binranges)
[nums idxs] = max(bincounts)
wd_out=binranges(idxs)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

```
wdd_phour=reshape(wdd,60,525600/60);  % get a matrix of size 60(min) X hours per year
mean_phour=mean(wdd_phour,1);         % compute the average of each 60 mins for every our in a year
```

Comment: Ander sorry my solution looks sort of similar to yours, but I had to post it as OP seemed to be looking for `hist` based solution and  the edits to be made for that in the comments didn't look proper, so posted a solution on that. Hope it looks fair to you, but you got +1! :)

Comment: @Divakar Definetly! go for it.